# Do this character's eyes have to turn white when she uses her superpower?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boys

In the final episode of *The Boys*, season 2, Victoria Neuman is revealed as the person who has the superpower to blow up people's heads left and right.

And we see her eyes turn milky white when she uses her power. But the question is:

- When she kills Vogelbaum and a few others during a public hearing in episode 7, her eyes are not white during the process.

Is there an official explanation?

[image: Victoria Neuman's white eyes]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to showrunner Eric Kripke in answer to a similar question from [**TVLine**](https://tvline.com/2020/10/09/the-boys-recap-season-2-finale-episode-8-stormfront-alive-dead/) it seems that the answer is YES!

> TVLINE: I rewatched the congressional hearing scene to look for any clues or hints or to see if Victoria’s eyes changed, and they didn’t. So has she really been the one exploding all the heads this season?
>
> KRIPKE: Yes, of course, she was. **Her eyes were pulsing off-camera.** But we tell everyone in Episode 1, if you go back after Raynor’s head explodes and they jumped in the van, Frenchie’s line is like, “Who do you know who can do this?!” and we cut to Victoria. She’s literally introduced with us saying like, “Here she is. This is the one who can do this.” Yeah, she blew up Congress.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, Victoria Neuman’s eyes do turn white when she uses her superpower. This is confirmed in a brief scene from *[Gen V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gen_V)* (*The Boys* spinoff) S01E07 “Sick”. Right after she makes someone’s head explode in front of her, you can see her eyes become milky white for a second.

Here’s a clip of that moment:

[image: Victoria Neuman’s eyes turning white]

This is a very subtle and quick change, so it’s easy for her to conceal it from others. That’s why she was able to easily hide it when she blew up several heads during the hearing in *The Boys* S02E07. It was also a clever way to lead up to the big reveal in the Season 2 finale.